# Regex to capture both uppercase and lowercase letter

Tags: c#, regex

I'm creating a simple C# application where in it has a condition to capture both uppercase and lowercase of a letter.

This is my condition:

```
if( txtChord.Text == "A" || txtChord.Text == "a" && cbKeys.SelectedIndex == 6 ){
                txtAnswer.Text = "B";
            }
```

I'd like to do this more efficiently using regex.

Comment: Checking if it is A or a is fine in this case. Don't use regex in this case. Also, if you can't figure put how to do regex, stop and learn first.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [`String.Compare(String, String, Boolean)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zkcaxw5y.aspx) method and supply true to the last argument to ignore case.

The method above returns negative, 0 or positive number.

If you only want `bool` value, you can use [`String.Equals(String, String, StringComparison)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t4411bks.aspx) with [`StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.stringcomparison.aspx) option.

Answer (score 3):

What is also often done to ignore case is somethig like this:

```
if( txtChord.Text.ToLower() == "a" && cbKeys.SelectedIndex == 6 )
```

But note that in your `if` statement the two checks are not "equivalent", because `&&` has higher [precendence](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691323%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) than `||`. Yours is equivalent to:

```
if( txtChord.Text == "A" || (txtChord.Text == "a" && cbKeys.SelectedIndex == 6))
```

Which cannot be replaced with a single check.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need regex to do this.  You can simple do:

```
if(txtChord.Text.ToLower() == "a" && cbKeys.SelectedIndex ==6)
{
     txtAnswer.Text = "B";
}
```

The `ToLower()` will make any text in the `txtChord` text box lowercase, and then you can check against that.  Or you can use `ToUpper()`.  It's the same thing, but with uppercase.

Answer (score 1):

Regex.Match(txtChord.Text,"a",RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)

Answer (score 0):

There is a ton of good information here: http://www.regular-expressions.info/

To catch either upper or lowercase of a letter you can use '[Aa]' or probably also with a flag.